# is calling context.getApplicationContext from a thread thread-safe?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

I wrote the following code to read a piece of data from the database but I'm not sure if the code is thread-safe or not since it calls `c.getApplicationContext` from a thread that's not the UI thread.

```
 public class chat extends AppCompatActivity
{
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        final Context myContext = this;
        AgentAsyncTask zx = new AgentAsyncTask(myContext);
        zx.execute();

        }

 private static class AgentAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Message>> {

        private Context c;
        public AgentAsyncTask(Context c) {
         this.c = c;

        }

        @Override
        protected List<Message> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            List<Message> x = AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(c.getApplicationContext()).userDao().getAll();
            return x;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Message> agentsCount) {
            Toast.makeText(c, agentsCount.get(0).message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Is this code thread safe ? the line that I suspect is not thread safe is :

```
List<Message> x = AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(c.getApplicationContext()).userDao().getAll();
```

Comment: Yes. as long as you don't mess with UI

Comment: @lvl4fi4 I am not messing with the UI, but my main concern is that I'm calling get ApplicationContext on an object that's declared  in the main thread , what if the main thread call the same function on the same object at the same time ?

Comment: @Tarek I'm more concerned about `agentsCount.get(0).message` and possible NPE :) Fromm what I can see, there is no problem in Your code. You're passing object from main thread to asynchronous task, but You're not changing  its state inside, so there should be no problem IMHO.

Comment: @www it's guaranteed that I'm going to have at least one "Agent" , and that's just a testing code. Thanks for your comment.